# How to push into github folder that contains two folders

Tags: github

I know maybe its stupid question but i have folder with two folders (client-side and server-side) of my site. Can somebody help me, because when i just add it, one of the folder didnt open in github.
[image]

Comment: "one of the folder didnt open in github" means what?!

Comment: folder was displaying however i click it it doesn't open., anyways i find out my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried everything from stack overflow, nothing was help but then i just deleted .git and try it again like usually. It was solution.

Just delete .git and try again....